# Custom ILogger implementation settings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to implement custom ILogger implementation for my work project. Everything works just fine, except for custom settings part.
Net Core documentation says that you can add different settings for specific providers

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug"
    },
    "Console": //this is it
    {
      "IncludeScopes": true
    }
  }
}
```

There is some aliases in documentation (for Console, Debug, Azure loggers etc), but I don't know how I should specify my custom provider in settings. I tried to use it's fully qualified name (`Full.Namespace.ClassName`), it's short name, it's name without "Logger" at the end, but it was of no help.
So, the question is:

**How can I force default asp net core ILogger implementation to actually use custom settings for my custom provider?**

**Edit 1.**
Actually, i sort it out by myself. You need to specify fully qualified name of custom `ILoggerProvider` (with full namespace and class name), not custom `ILogger`. Then default logging framework will use custom settings for all loggers, spawned by this implementation of ILoggerProvider

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the Options system an consume it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: From documentation it's look like all custom settings (scopes, min/max level, overrides for them) will be handled by default LoggerFactory / LoggerProvider. Because otherwise it's useful only for default log providers, since i can force user to specify them by hand in code